# Android Studio choosing the emulator instead of running last one automatically

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to test multiple screen sizes and is annoying having to shut down the emulator then open a new one just to check the size (there is a new font so I can't view it in the editor).

I open multiple emulators but the box doesn't appear to select the emulator it just runs the previous one.

> I searched the answers here and they said go to  Run > Edit
>   Configurations and Select emulator as Target or simply check the
>   checkbox Use same device for future launches.

I am obviously wanting the opposite so it would be unchecked. The thing is the box is unchecked but it is not giving me the option to select.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It should work if the box is unchecked. Probably a bug of android studio? In any case, I've found that clicking stop and then running again gives you the option to select device.

[image]

Click the stop button on the right to kill the app and then run again.

Comment: Awesome that works! Thanks. I will accept the answer when it is available.